# Xcode LLDB Print Statements Fail - NSUndoManager

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb, nsundomanager

I have a breakpoint set and want to print my UITextField's superview. I type `po myTextField.superview` but I receive the following error:

```
error: instance method 'undoManager' has incompatible result types in different translation units ('id' vs. 'NSUndoManager *')
note: instance method 'undoManager' also declared here
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

What does this mean and how can I print my superview? I found a link that provides a janky workaround in code: http://openradar.io/15890965, but I would like a better solution.

Comment: Same story here: I try `po tableView.gestureRecognizers` on a category of `UITableView`.

Comment: I have seen this error many times when trying to po frame, bounds, recursiveDescription, constraints, etc. (only built-in methods). Seems to be a crippling xcode/lldb bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People of the world: I have an answer!

To dodge all UIKit errors: Before typing your `po` statement, type the line -- `expr @import UIKit`

If you want to turn this on for your app globally, then add the following breakpoint in your app delegate:

[image]

Thanks to Craig Hockenberry and Steve Streza for the update (found [here](http://furbo.org/2015/05/11/an-import-ant-change-in-xcode)).

Comment: This article tells you how to turn this on for all projects: http://merowing.info/2015/12/little-things-that-can-make-your-life-easier-in-2016/

Answer (score 1):

The solution I use to prevent this error while debugging is to **explicitly cast everything**.

In your case I would do

```
po [(UITextField *)myTextField superView]
```

Comment: From initial testing, this seems to work for me. However, the 2nd comment in the link above (http://openradar.io/15890965) claims that it happens for them, even when explicitly casting. Anyone else want to chime in?

Comment: I tried explicitly casting and still get this error. e.g.    

    po (NSString *)[((IBAdBannerView *)adView) recursiveDescription]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any custom accessor methods for 'myTextField'? I have seen this same issue a number of times and it is usually caused by the po trying to print a property for an object that gets initialized the first time its getter is called. For example, if I try to run 'po self.imageView.contentMode' on a UITableViewCell I get that same error. Try moving your breakpoint to a point in the code where you know that 'myTextField' has been fully initialized.

Comment: I do not have a custom accessor method for myTextField. Good thought though.

Answer (score 0):

Does `myTextField` really point to a `UITextField`? That's one reason this error will show up. For instance, the following code will compile, and if I set a breakpoint on the third line, I can enter `po b.superview` to reproduce the error you saw.

```
NSString *a = @"not a view";
UITextField *b = (UITextField *)a;
UIView *view = b.superview;
```

Try typing `po [myTextField class]` at your LLDB prompt to see if it's actually a `UITextField`. It could be another type of object, or `nil`.

Comment: `myTextField` does point to a `UITextField` (through an outlet).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in Xcode 5.1.1 and fixed it by quitting Xcode 5.1.1 and trying Xcode 6. Rebooting Xcode 5.1.1 for Xcode 5.1.1 may also work for some people.

Comment: I have not yet found this error with Xcode 6, so Apple may have fixed it. It'll take some more time before we're sure though.